# Como devolver un único valor usando Ajax para mostrar un mensaje de alerta

Tags: javascript, mysql, html5, ajax

estoy tratando de implementar un buscador. Es decir en base a un valor que se ingresa en un campo de texto necesito devolver un mensaje de alerta indicando si dicho valor se encuentra o no en la base de datos mostrando un mensaje de alerta. Para ello estoy realizando lo siguiente.

```js
var sugestion = false;

function validarAutosugestion(event, input) {
  var cod = event.which;
  if (cod == null) cod = event.keyCode;
  if ((cod == 8) || (cod >= 48 && cod <= 57) || (cod >= 96 && cod <= 105)) {
    if ((cod == 8) || (cod >= 48 && cod <= 57) || (cod >= 96 && cod <= 105)) sugestion = true;
    return true;
  } else return false;
}

function activarAutosugestion(input) {
  if (sugestion) {
    sugestion = false;
    $("#imagen").empty();
    busquedaPaciente(input.value);
  }
}

function busquedaPaciente(texto) {
  if (texto.length == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  $.ajax({
      "url": "lib/gestion/historia_clinica/procesar_busqueda_paciente.php",
      "type": "post",
      "dataType": "json",
      "data": {
        "clave": texto
      }
    }).done(function(data, statusText) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.valor.length; i++) {
        if (data.valor[i].resultado == 1) {
         alert('El paciente cuenta con una historia clinica.');
        }
        alert('El paciente no tiene con una historia clinica.');
      }
    })
    .fail(function(data, statusText) {
      alert(statusText);
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="divAutosugestion" class="form-group inner-addon right-addon">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
  <input id="textCampoBuscar" type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="activarAutosugestion(this)" onkeypress="return validarAutosugestion(event,this)" placeholder="Ingrese el dni del paciente" maxlength="8" autofocus/>
</div>
```

**Codigo PHP**

```
<?php 
   $clave = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"clave");
   //echo $clave;
   require_once '../../../files/clases/Conexion.php';
   $respuesta = '{"valor":[]}';
   $conexion = Conexion::establecer();
   if(!$conexion->connect_error){
       $sql = "SELECT IF(COUNT(id_historia_clinica) > 0,1, 0) as resultado FROM Historia_Clinica_Paciente WHERE paciente_id = ( SELECT id_paciente FROM Paciente WHERE dni = '".$clave."%'";
       if($resultado = $conexion->query($sql)){
           $respuesta = '{"valor":'.json_encode($resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)).'}';

           $resultado->free_result();
           }
       else echo $conexion->error;
       $conexion->close();
   }

   echo $respuesta;

?>
```

Como debería ser la comunicación con la base de datos usando ajax? Dado que me esta devolviendo un "parsererror".

Lo que estaría necesitando es devolver un valor y luego analizarlo desde JavaScript y no recorrer un objeto json. Esto es posible?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

podrias probar a hacer lo siguiente en la petición :

```
function busquedaPaciente(texto) {
  if (texto.length == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  $.ajax({
      "url": "lib/gestion/historia_clinica/procesar_busqueda_paciente.php",
      "type": "post",
      "dataType": "json",
      "data": {
        "clave": texto
      }
    }).done(function(data, statusText) {
       //verifica de la presencia de datos al interno de la respuesta 
       if (!$.isEmptyObject(data.valor)) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.valor.length; i++) {
              if (data.valor[i].resultado == 1) {
                  alert('El paciente cuenta con una historia clinica.');
              }else
                  alert('El paciente no tiene con una historia clinica.');
          }
       }else
          alert ("El paciente buscado no esta presente en nuestro database");
    })
    .fail(function(data, statusText) {
      alert(statusText);
    });
}
```

en este modo gracias a `$.isEmptyObject()` controlamos si el valor restituido esta vacio,en este caso con la negacion `!` comprabamos si tiene contenido. Si esta ultima condición se cumple entramos a ver si el paciente buscado tiene un historial o menos, en caso contrario comunicamos que el paciente buscado no esta al interno del database.

espero que te sea de ayuda! exitos